# How to make monk findoneandupdate property a variable?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, monk

I'm trying to find and update a field in a document using Monk. The problem is, I am trying to using a variable in the property area. (property: value) The type, and the value.

```
let result = await collection.findOneAndUpdate({type: value}, { $set: { blacklisted: false} })
```

When I set type to for example, apple with `let type = "apple"` it does not use the type variable in findOneAndUpdate.

Where as if I just put apple in like this

```
let result = await collection.findOneAndUpdate({"apple": value}, { $set: { blacklisted: false} })
```

It worked 100% fine.

I have tried making this an object too, like this: `let obj = {type, value}` then putting that into the find and update `let result = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(obj, { $set: { blacklisted: false} })`

Yet, still no luck. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the value of a variable as a key, you should use brackets `[]`

```js
let type = "apple"
let result = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { [type]: value },  <----- Using [] on type variable 
  { $set: { blacklisted: false } }
);
```